# "ReInstalling" openCV after installing ROS

Tags: ros, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I installed ROS Indigo some time ago and in that time I was going to install Opencv separately to learn about this library, however a professor told me that once I install ROS, I also install opencv and reinstalling it could cause trouble. Is it true? (I was reading something from ROS and I read some things saying that OpenCV is somehow like ROS independent now, this is why I ask if I have to install it separately from the opencv web page) Additionally I would like to ask if here I can also ask about Opencv or I can just ask about ROS.

By the way. I'm using ROS indigo.

Thanks for your answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206271/%22reinstalling%22-opencv-after-installing-ros/) by [Diego](https://answers.ros.org/users/21507/diego/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since Indigo, OpenCV is not released from ROS infrastructure.

Here you can ask only Ros questions, but if you have question related to them both then you can post it here too.

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Diego](https://answers.ros.org/users/21507/diego/) on 2015-04-09**:
Thanks for your answer. I just found openCV. I thought I had to install it separately.